# Determining directory equivalence (Windows)

Tags: windows, filesystems

Say I have two directory paths:

`C:\Shares\Apple\Orange`

and

`\\MACHINENAME\Apple\Orange`

Is there a way to (programmatically) determine if they refer to the same directory? In general, can I determine whether two directory references are equivalent without comparing paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can try.  It may choke on some things.  I haven't tested it.

1. Call [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) on each directory with `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`.
2. Call [`GetFileInformationByHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952(VS.85).aspx) on both handles.
3. Compare file index, volume serial number.
4. Call [GetVolumeInformationByHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964920(VS.85).aspx).
5. Compare volume name.

You are right to say that comparing paths is a bad idea.  Symbolic links, short names, and drive letter mappings get in your way that way.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without explicit out-of-band cooperation from `\\MACHINENAME`. On Windows, the SMB protocol exposes no method to obtain a GUID uniquely identifying the underlying volume. The protocol doesn't even guarantee that you're looking at an actual volume.